# Retina support in Sphinx-generated graphics

Tags: css, graphviz, retina-display, python-sphinx

When I use Sphinx extensions (such as [Graphviz](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/graphviz.html) or [`inheritance_diagram`](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/inheritance.html)) to render images in Sphinx HTML documentation, the resulting images are blurry and of low quality on my Mac and iOS devices because, presumably, Sphinx (at least by default) is doing nothing to [provide for pixel doubling](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/SafariImageDeliveryBestPractices/Introduction/Introduction.html) on these targets.

Is there something I can do — a Sphinx or Graphviz setting, or theme modification, perhaps — that will create pages that render properly on Retina systems.

---

Note that the issue here is for Sphinx-generated graphics. Having to manually create additional images at higher resolutions is not an option?